# Suppress "Finishing Installation ..." message in install4j custom application

Tags: install4j

I'm writing a custom application in install4j that would act as version checker. And i intend to output the newest available version when it runs. But when it run it also prints "Finishing installation ..." to the output and i was wondering whether there's a way to suppress that

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to suppress the message, but you can override it to the empty string.

On the General Settings->Languages step, set up a custom localization file, then open the built-in editor and enter the line

```
StatusRunProgram=
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this would remove the message from normal installer program. I was hoping to suppress this message only for the custom program only.

Comment: install4j 6.1 will have a separate message for custom installer applications that will not use the work "installation".

Comment: Where can I get a list of those key values for the string localized text?

Comment: All messages are in `resource/messages/messages_en.utf8`